# Pulling a value as string and using it as a column name for dfs in list

Tags: r, list, purrr

I would like to use the first value of a helper-column, which contains the same string in each row, as the column name for the column which has the actual values. The dfs are stored in a list. Is there a way to handle this with `purrr`? (I have tried but did not find a solution)

Example:

```
# Create dataframe
df1 = data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 3),
  B = c("df1", "df1", "df1")
)

# Create another dataframe
df2 = data.frame(
  A = c(4, 5, 6),
  B = c("df2", "df2", "df2")
)

# Create list of data frames
list1 = list(df1, df2)
```

And this is how i would like the dfs to look like within the list:

```
[[1]]
  df1   
1 1 
2 2 
3 3 

[[2]]
  df2  
1 4 
2 5 
3 6
```

I really appreciate any ideas and solutions, thanks!!

I have tried with plucking the first value that contains the string but I can't think of a solution that allows me to map the values as new column names to the list.

Comment: Maybe `lapply(list1, \(x) setNames(x[-2], x[[2]][1]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for Tim's solution if possible, however, if your dataframes are named differently than the B column you could do

```
  first_data = data.frame(
    A = c(1, 2, 3),
    B = c("df1", "df1", "df1")
  )
  
  # Create another dataframe
  second_data = data.frame(
    A = c(4, 5, 6),
    B = c("df2", "df2", "df2")
  )

  library(purrr)
  library(dplyr)
  list(first_data,second_data) |> 
    set_names(c((first_data$B[1]), second_data$B[1])) |> 
    map(~.x |> select(-B))

$df1
  A
1 1
2 2
3 3

$df2
  A
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tibble::lst` to create a named list of `data.frame`s and then use `map` to deselect the `B` column:

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

list1 = lst(df1, df2)
list1 %>% 
  map(~ select(.x, !B))

#> $df1
#>   A
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
#> 3 3
#> 
#> $df2
#>   A
#> 1 4
#> 2 5
#> 3 6
```

Data from OP

```r
# Create dataframe
df1 = data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 3),
  B = c("df1", "df1", "df1")
)

# Create another dataframe
df2 = data.frame(
  A = c(4, 5, 6),
  B = c("df2", "df2", "df2")
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>